# Is it easy to create and control a hand model in Blender?

Tags: unity

I am working on a project that requires a digital interface to display my physical hand movements on the screen. As an example, leap motion AR devices track hand movements and you can see how the hands move in Unity game engine or in the leap motion software. I wanted to do something similar where I pass my hand data in real time to the software and it renders the motion of my hand, but doing this in Unity seemed difficult.

I have never used Blender before, but I wanted to know if something like this is easy to do in Blender before I start learning how to use it.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe look at https://developer-archive.leapmotion.com/documentation/python/index.html as Blender uses Python...

Comment: If I were to use leapmotion in Blender, I would still need to create my own hand from scratch?